# Tools cannot connect to ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch running in a docker container with an exposed 9200 port.
I can access it using the browser and using `curl` on `http://192.168.59.103:9200/` (I get the `You Know, for Search` response), but no other GUI tools seems to be able to connect, they are all unable to connect.

I've tried [elasticsearch-head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head), [elastic-hammer](https://github.com/andrewvc/elastic-hammer), [ElasticHQ](http://www.elastichq.org/), etc.

How can that even be if I can get a response, they should too? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

That is really interesting. But when I am encountering such a problems with Elasticsearch I am trying the following:

1. Curl (you had tried that)
2. Browser (you had tried that), but here I am starting in paraller Browser debugger (e.g. by pressing F12) to see what exactly goes as request and what exactly comes as responce.

Next steps:
3. Start sniffer like Wireshark and
4. execute connection from the tools.

If the calls from Browser/Curl are similar to what you see in Wireshark then something is pretty odd. But perhaps they (tools) are misconfigured and they are sending requests to wrong machine or they are using wrong API or even they use wrong port or authentication.